# iOS 7 Video not playing MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c, ios7

This code is working perfect in iOS 8 . but unable to play video in iOS7.The player shows up but plays nothing.Thanks

```
NSString *url = @"http://.../playlist.m3u8";
NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
self.streamPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:streamURL];
self.streamPlayer.controlStyle= MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
self.streamPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
self.streamPlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.streamPlayer.view];
[self.streamPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.streamPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

When you add a movie player’s view to your app’s view hierarchy, be sure to size the frame correctly, as shown here:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =
        [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[myView addSubview: player.view];
// ...
[player play];
```

Try to set the frame of your video player.